# calculating a limit with problem with l'hopital's law

Tags: limits

I need some help in calculating this limit:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow2}(x-1)^{\frac{2x^2-8}{x^2-4x+4}}$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: at x=2 !! sorry for not writing in main passage

Comment: Is the limit of interest given by $\lim_{x\to 2}(x-1)^{(2x^2-8)/(x^2-4x+4)}$?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Hint: calculate the limit of the power first, using L'Hopital's law. Does not work since the limit is $\pm\infty$? Then transform your expression via $\log(a^b)=b\log(a)$. Then if $b\rightarrow\infty$, $1/b\rightarrow0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINTS:

First, note that

$$\frac{2x^2-8}{x^2-4x+4}=\frac{2(x+2)}{x-2}$$

Hence, we can write

$$(x-1)^{\frac{2(x+2)}{x-2}}=e^{\frac{2(x+2)}{x-2}\log(x-1)}$$

Finish by using L'Hospital's Rule to show

$$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{2(x+2)}{x-2}\log(x-1)=\lim_{x\to 2}\left(2\log(x-1)+\frac{2(x+2)}{x-1}\right)$$

Comment: alright, got it!

Comment: Pleased to hear.  Well done.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably better to do a change of variable, $x=t+2$, so the exponent becomes
$$
\frac{2x^2-8}{x^2-4x+4}=\frac{2(x-2)(x+2)}{(x-2)^2}=2\frac{x+2}{x-2}=2\frac{t+4}{t}
$$
Thus the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\bigl((1+t)^{1/t}\bigr)^{2(t+4)}
$$
Now it's a matter of computing
$$
l=\lim_{t\to0}(1+t)^{1/t}
$$
and then the sought limit is $l^8$.